# Applying REINFORCE to easy21

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to apply the REINFORCE algorithm (with SoftMax policy, undiscounted Gt with baseline) on David Silver's easy21, and I am having problems with the actual implementation. When compared to a pure MC approach, the produced result does not converge to Q*. Here is the related code:

```
hit = True
stick = False
actions = [hit, stick]

alpha = 0.1
theta = np.random.randn(420).reshape((420,1))

def psi(state, action):
    
    if state.player < 1 or state.player > 21:
        return np.zeros((420, 1))
    
    dealers = [int(state.dealer == x + 1) for x in range(0, 10)]
    players = [int(state.player == x + 1) for x in range(0, 21)]
    actions = [int(action == hit), int(action == stick)]
    
    psi = [1 if (i == 1 and j == 1 and k == 1) else 0
           for i in dealers for j in players for k in actions]

    return np.array(psi).reshape((420, 1)) 
    
def Q(state, action, weight):
    return np.matmul(psi(state, action).T, weight)
    
def softmax(state, weight):
    
    allQ = [Q(state, a, weight) for a in actions]
    
    probs = np.exp(allQ) / np.sum(np.exp(allQ))
    
    return probs.reshape((2,))

def score_function(state, action, weight):

    probs = softmax(state, weight)
    
    expected_score = (probs[0] * psi(state, hit)) + (probs[1] * psi(state, stick))
    
    return psi(state, action) - expected_score

def softmax_policy(state, weight):
    
    probs = softmax(state, weight)
    
    if np.random.random() < probs[1]:
        return stick
    else:
        return hit


if __name__ == "__main__":    

    Q_star = np.load('Q_star.npy')

    for k in range(1, ITERATIONS):
        terminal = False
        
        state = game.initialise_state()
        action = softmax_policy(state, theta)
        
        history = [state, action]
        
        while not terminal:
            state, reward = game.step(state, action)
            action = softmax_policy(state, theta)
            
            terminal = state.terminal
            
            if terminal:
                state_action_pairs = zip(history[0::3], history[1::3])
                
                history.append(reward)
                history.append(state)
                
                Gt = sum(history[2::3])
                
                for s, a in state_action_pairs:
                    advantage = Gt - Q(s, a, prev_theta)
                    theta += alpha * score_function(s, a, theta) * advantage
          
            else:
                history.append(reward)
                history.append(state)
                history.append(action)
                
        if k % 10000 == 0:
            print("MSE: " + str(round(np.sum((Q_star - generate_Q(theta)) ** 2),2)))
```

Output:

```
python reinforce.py
MSE: 288.18
MSE: 248.45
MSE: 227.08
MSE: 215.46
MSE: 207.3
MSE: 202.61
MSE: 197.82
MSE: 195.96
MSE: 194.01
```

The table below shows the value function created using this algorithm:
[image: value function created by REINFORCE]

Update:
Fixed the code by using a different theta initialisation:

```
theta = np.zeros((420,1))
```

Current value function:
[image: value function created by REINFORCE - updated]

But the current value function still does not match Q*
(missing peak at player sum = 11)

The entire code is available at:
https://github.com/Soundpulse/easy21-rl/blob/main/reinforce.py